# Share ngTableParams across angular controllers

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

I am fairly new to angular and trying to remove some code duplication.  I have two controllers attached to 2 different views.  Both views call off to a server to get statistics data which they then display in a table.  I am using ngtable.  At this point both controllers have a configuration block for the ngtable that is exactly the same.  The only difference in between the tables is that one of them displays several more columns than the other.  Anyway I have this code in both controllers:

```
 $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
        page: 1,            // show first page
        count: 10,           // count per page
        sorting: {
            groupName: 'asc'     // initial sorting
        }
    }, {
        total: $scope.data.length, // length of data
        getData: function ($defer, params) {

            if (!$scope.validInputs())
                return;

            var orderedData = $scope.data;
            orderedData = $scope.filterText ?
                orderedData.filter(filter) :
                orderedData;

            orderedData = params.sorting() ?
                $filter('orderBy')(orderedData, params.orderBy()) :
                orderedData;

            params.total(orderedData.length); // set total for recalc pagination
            $scope.page = orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count());
            $defer.resolve($scope.page);
        }
    });
```

What would be a good way to remove this duplication?

Answer (score 0):

You can use set ngTableDefaults.

```
app.value('ngTableDefaults', {
    params: {
        page: 10,            // show first page
        count: 100,          // count per page
        sorting: {
            groupName: 'asc'     // initial sorting
        }
    },
    settings: {}
});
```